# Montar os parâmetros de um URL dinamicamente

Tags: php, get

Tenho uma página em um sistema onde listo os produtos cadastrados no BD, estou implementando alguns filtros dentro dessa página, e gostaria de ir atualizando os *links* dos filtros conforme solicitados no URL (REQUISIÇÃO GET):

Ao iniciar a pagina o *links* dos filtros nela contidos deveram iniciar da seguinte forma:

## Categoria

```
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=1">Categoria 1</a> 
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=2">Categoria 2</a> 
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=3">Categoria 3</a>
```

## Numeracao

```
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_numeracao=34">34</a>
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_numeracao=35">35</a>
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_numeracao=36">36</a>
```

Caso o usuário acesse o filtro da página os *link`s* deverão atualizar da seguinte forma:

Se acessar o filtro **categoria** os links do filtro **numeração** deveram ficar:

```
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=1&_numeracao=34">34</a>
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=1&_numeracao=35">35</a>
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=1&_numeracao=36">36</a>
```

Se acessar o filtro **numeração** os *links* do filtro **categoria** deveram ficar:

```
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=1&_numeracao=34">Categoria 1</a>
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=2&_numeracao=34">Categoria 2</a>
<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=3&_numeracao=34">Categoria 3</a>
```

Gostaria de um direcionamento por onde começar, pois não estou encontrado a lógica de como fazer.

Comment: Tu queres apanhar os valores ou mantê-los na URL?

Comment: @JorgeB.Quero manter na URL pegar os valores e inserir no link dos filtros.

Comment: Você fez uma pergunta achando que é a melhor maneira de criar um filtro para os seus produtos, mas não tem a mínima ideia de uma lógica para isso. Aconselho a você mostrar o que tem e não somente uma parte. E faça perguntas mais concisas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com o mesmo princípio da resposta do @JorgeB, adaptei para a geração dos filtros especificados na edição da pergunta. Aproveitando, acrescentei uma opção para remoção de um filtro existente:

```
<?php
   $categoria = $_GET['_categoria'];
   $numeracao = $_GET['_numeracao'];

   $f_categoria = empty( $categoria ) ? '' :'&_categoria='.$categoria;
   $f_numeracao = empty( $numeracao ) ? '' :'&_numeracao='.$numeracao;

   if ( empty( $categoria ) ) {
      echo '<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=1'.$f_numeracao.'">Categoria 1</a>';
      echo '<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=2'.$f_numeracao.'">Categoria 2</a>';
      echo '<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria=2'.$f_numeracao.'">Categoria 3</a>';
   } else {
      echo '<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_categoria='.$f_numeracao.'">Todas as categorias</a>';
   }

   if ( empty( $numeracao ) ) {
      echo '<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_numeracao=33'.$f_categoria.'">Numero 33</a>';
      echo '<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_numeracao=34'.$f_categoria.'">Numero 34</a>';
      echo '<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_numeracao=35'.$f_categoria.'">Numero 35</a>';
   } else {
      echo '<a href="meusite.com.br/produtos?_numeracao='.$f_categoria.'">Todas as numeracoes</a>';
   }
?>
```

Caso você vá fazer algo mais complexo, com muitos filtros diferentes, compensa automatizar o processo todo, usando por exemplo *arrays* e *loops*.

Comment: Afinal entendeste a pergunta do mesmo jeito. Eu só respondi a uma edição da pergunta diferente :)

Comment: @JorgeB. Pois é, por isso acho errado o -1 na sua. Da forma que estava a questão, você fez o que podia.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela atenção, como podem ver estou começando a utilizar o SO, como perdi a lógica postei o que tinha em mente para buscar um direcionamento e diante da minha pergunta confusa acabei encontrando esse direcionamento. Mais um vez obrigado! @Bacco

Comment: @VitorMolina estamos aqui pra isso. Se puder, detalhe mais as próximas perguntas, pois aumenta a chance de darmos boas respostas, e evita que os colegas invistam um tempo baseado em suposições erradas ;)

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer isso com um simples [`GET`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
$categoria = $_GET['_categoria'];
$cor       = $_GET['_cor'];
$tamanho   = $_GET['_tamanho'];
```

depois é só verificar se os campos estão preenchidos:

```
$url  = "Location: meusite.com.br/produtos.php?";

if(!empty($categoria)) 
    $url .= "_categoria=$categoria";

if(!empty($cor) && substr($url, -1)!="?")
    $url .= "&_cor=$cor";
else if(!empty($cor) && substr($url, -1)=="?")
    $url .= "_cor=$cor";

if(!empty($tamanho) && substr($url, -1)!="?")
    $url .= "&_tamanho=$tamanho";
else if(!empty($tamanho) && substr($url, -1)=="?")
    $url .= "_tamanho=$tamanho";

header('$url');
```

Esta resposta é a resposta a primeira publicação do AP, de qualquer forma a ideia é a mesma e para a última edição basta consultar a [resposta do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53825/7210).

Comment: Estou com grande dificuldade en perceber o que ele quer @Bacco

Comment: Eu acho que entendi, vou arriscar uma resposta então.

Comment: @Bacco vai em frente :)

Comment: Mas eu acho que o -1 que deram está exagerado aqui, pois a pergunta poderia ser melhor formulada.

Comment: @Bacco eu respondi conforme percebi, e olha que li umas quantas vezes. Se vires a minha primeira resposta da pra ver o que já pensei outra coisa. Devia era ter fechado, em vez de tentar perceber. Fica assim até o AP dizer alguma coisa ou a sua resposta salvar a pergunta.

Comment: de qq forma upei a sua, pq eu acho que se há problema, não é na resposta.

Comment: @Bacco Eu reli e continuo sem entender, daria a mesma resposta lol

Comment: Por isso dei o negativo, Jorge B. Você ainda continua sem entender e respondeu sem entender.

Comment: @Lollipop O que é estranho, pois e se o autor gostar da resposta dele? Pode ser que você não tenha entendido e o JorgeB sim. Acho meio complicado alguém votar se também não entendeu. Aliás, é um dos maiores problemas do SOpt.

Comment: Não tem nada de estranho e você sabe muito bem que não é isso.

Comment: É, "estranho" é uma maneira educada de dizer.

Comment: @Bacco eu entendi a pergunta, da minha forma e respondi. Vamos ver o que diz o AP se aparecer...

Comment: Meu teclado está ruim. Desculpem.

Comment: @Lollipop No mundo ideal ninguém deveria responder uma pergunta confusa, mas a SE não quer assim, então todo mundo está respondendo o que interpreta correto e corre os riscos inerentes disto. Mas assim como não é possível positivar sem saber se está certo, não pode negativar sem saber se está errado. Para votar positivo ou negativo tem que ter certeza que o voto é adequado. Não pode ser uma suposição, até porque a pessoa esquece de mudar depois. Quem responde não esquece porque as pessoas vão interagir com a resposta, com o voto isto não acontece.

Comment: @bigown devia era estar fechada

Comment: Estou esclarecido @bigown. Somente fiz o que fizeram comigo e aprendi, mas agora irei substituir por este aprendizado. Pode ditar a resposta @Jorge? Vamos esquecer toda essa confusão!

Comment: @Lollipop mas se estiver errado mesmo, se a pessoa não pode consertar (avisar a pessoa para consertar um problema é prioridade), aí é para negativar. Coisas que você tem certeza que está errado e não será consertado merece negativo para ajudar classificar o conteúdo, separar o joio do trigo. Sinto muito que alguém tenha cotado indevidamente em alguma coisa sua. Mas também precisa ver se a pessoa não tinha convicção que estava errado. De qualquer forma ela deveria lhe avisar para arrumar.

Comment: @Lollipop editei, mas achei desnecessário alterar a resposta. Adicionei uma explicação.