# Variável global em todas as funções da classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, classes, variáveis

Normalmente quando quero puxar uma variável que está fora da classe, eu uso `global $variavel`, porém queria que essa variável fosse acessível em todas as funções da classe, pra não ficar precisando "puxar" em todas as funções, como fazer?

Comment: Você quer deixar de usar `global`, que é bom, e pegar uma variável não global que deve sobreviver durante toda aplicação facilmente dentro de cada função?

Comment: A classe tem um construtor ?

Comment: Sim e sim @Zuul

Comment: Por que você quer obter uma variável de fora da classe? Os parâmetros servem justamente para passar para os métodos o que eles precisam.

Comment: A variável deve ser global mesmo, deve durar por toda a aplicação e estar disponível para todas as classes ou ela é uma variável que deve pertencer a uma classe?

Comment: @Oeslei a variavel é de conexao com db..

Comment: Ia postar comment na outra pergunta, mas como vc deletou, segue aqui uma tabela extensa de primos: http://primes.utm.edu/primes/download.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O meu entendimento da pergunta é que é necessário guardar os dados da conexão em uma variável que possa ser acessada de qualquer ponto da aplicação. Uma variável global é uma solução para isto mas de fato não é bom usá-la.

Então a solução é encapsular a variável que não é global em uma função mantendo seu estado de forma estática ou usando uma abordagem considerada mais moderna, mas não necessariamente melhor, encapsulando a variável em uma classe estática.

Note que ser estático é o segredo por que isto dá um tempo de vida para a variável igual ao tempo da aplicação, ou seja, a variável fica disponível o tempo todo exatamente como a variável global fica mas tem a vantagem da variável não ser exposta diretamente criando ambiguidades e conflitos com outras variáveis locais. É melhor ter funções ou classes globais. Mesmo isto pode não ser a solução ideal, alguns criticariam esta solução que é pragmática.

```
class Conexao {
    private static $conexao = "dados da conexao aqui - classe";
    public static function PegaConexao() {
        return self::$conexao;
    }
}

function conexao(){
    static $conexao = "dados da conexao aqui - funcao";
    return $conexao;
}

class Uso {
    public function AbreBanco1() {
        echo conexao() . "\n";
    }
    public function AbreBanco2() {
        echo Conexao::PegaConexao();
    }
}

Uso::AbreBanco1(); //chama só para demonstrar
Uso::AbreBanco2(); //chama só para demonstrar
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/G1FCU1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zpwoqsdp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/StaticVar.php).

Como a pergunta não dá detalhes só posso mostrar uma solução genérica mas é fácil adaptar para uso conforme a necessidade específica.

Não precisa ter as duas formas, coloquei as duas para exemplificar, obviamente só um `AbreBanco()` existiria de fato. E o conteúdo da variável provavelmente será outro.

Comment: Seu exemplo é extenso e complexo. Diferente do meu que trata-se de uma resposta mais direta e sem o uso de variáveis privadas estáticas e/ou métodos estáticos.

Comment: Utilize métodos estáticos somente para funções onde não há necessidade de alterar o estado interno de um objeto. Normalmente métodos estáticos são métodos auxiliares, escritos para dar suporte genérico a outros métodos. Um exemplo é um método de ordenação de vetor: ele recebe um vetor como parâmetro e ordena-o, retornando em seguida. Ele pode ser usado em diversos locais, porém não altera o estado interno de nenhum objeto. Logo, ele é um ótimo candidato a se tornar um método estático.

Comment: Extenso e complexo? Tem certeza? Eu acho o mais mais curto e mais simples. Note que eu mostrei duas formas diferentes para ele escolher. Mas faz o que ele pediu, a sua resposta não faz. A sua não deixa o conteúdo disponível para todas as funções de todas as classes. Na sua o conteúdo morre quando a variável `$a` sai de escopo. As pessoas só votaram na sua porque não entenderam o problema. Depois de ler seu segundo só posso dizer "Amém". Isto é o que se lê em manuais de boas práticas que não ajudam resolver problema algum. Por isto eu os abomino. Ditam regras e não resolvem problemas.

Comment: Mas de qualquer forma note que eu não altero estado interno em nenhum momento, em nenhum dos dois casos. Você faz isto, mas o problema não pedia para fazer isto.

Comment: Não adianta "enfeitar" a resposta quando o objetivo é outro: "`...queria que essa variável fosse acessível em todas as funções **da classe**`". Você foi além. Sua resposta consome mais códigos.

Comment: Leia os comentários, lá ele esclarece e dá mais detalhes de como ele quer. Você pode reclamar que a pergunta originalmente não estava dando todos os detalhes mas ele escolheu a minha resposta como a correta porque ela resolve o problema real dele. É o mesmo caso que tinha acontecido lá na outra pergunta, o JorgeB deu uma resposta que parecia certa mas não estava e aí apareceu o Bacco e deu a resposta certa porque ele entendeu melhor o problema mesmo a pergunta não ajudando muito.

Comment: Ele não respondeu a sua última pergunta. Por tanto, a variável deve pertencer a mesma classe e acessível a todas as funções da mesma, conforme a pergunta.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53794/vari%c3%a1vel-global-em-todas-as-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-da-classe/53797?noredirect=1#comment110288_53794 os dois "sim" são para os comentários anteriores, depois que eu percebi, por isso ele não respondeu mais, já estava respondido.

Answer (score 4):

Criar variável acessível para todas as funções de uma classe:

```
<?php

    class teste {

        /* construct */
        function __construct($variavel) {

            $this->global_variavel  = $variavel;

        }

        function checando_funcao() {

                echo $this->global_variavel;

        }

        function checando_funcao2() {

                echo $this->global_variavel;

        }

?>
```

- Para executar um teste:

  ```
      //Criando uma nova instância

      $variavel = 'Meu texto!';
      $a = new teste($variavel);

      //Executando as duas funções com os mesmos valores de uma única variável "global"
      $a->checando();  
      $a->checando_funcao2();
  ```

*Obs:*

> Para garantir compatibilidade reversa, se o PHP 5 não conseguir achar uma __construct() para uma determinada classe, ele procurará pela função construtora à moda-antiga, que tenha o mesmo nome da classe. Efetivamente, significa que o único caso que pode gerar problemas de compatibilidade seria se a classe tiver um método chamado __construct() que fosse usado para outra finalidade que não inicializar o objeto.

Comment: A sua resposta estritamente está errada. Mas a pergunta inicialmente não estava muito clara. É o mesmo problema que você reclamou nesse comentário: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53689/montar-os-par%c3%a2metros-de-um-url-dinamicamente/53692#comment110408_53692 Até por coerência não estou pregando o negativo na sua resposta mas ela está errada para o que o autor quer. Você só teve esses positivos porque as pessoas também não entenderam bem o que a pergunta queria. Então dá para entender que ela não estava bem formulada. O que você vai fazer agora que sabe que ela está errada?

Comment: Mostre-me as fontes, as regras e prove-me que estou errado quanto ao escopo.

Comment: A sua é igual a minha? Não é, a sua faz outra coisa diferente do que foi pedido. A minha foi aceita na hora, a sua ficou disponível por horas e o autor não considerou certa. Só autor pode provar qual está certa e ele fez isto quando aceitou. Só poderia ter duas certas se as duas produzissem o mesmo resultado, mesmo que de maneiras diferentes. A sua produz um resultado diferente do esperado, a sua perde o estado quando sai do escopo, ele não quer isto.

Comment: Acho que o autor deve ter se impressionado com uma resposta feita por uma reputação de 44k+ e disse: "Nossa! Era isso que precisava. Uma fonte confiável."`Talvez!`

Comment: Como você começou menosprezar a inteligência do autor especulando que ele não sabe o que resolve o problema dele, o que até poderia ser o caso se ele já não tivesse demonstrado que consegue se virar bem com uma informação adequada e não precisa ser tutelado, eu percebo que você não vai mudar de ideia após eu mostrar os fatos para você, não posso dizer mais nada. Se a minha estivesse errada eu reconheceria, consertaria ou apagaria, como já fiz outras vezes.

Answer (score 1):

Para tornar uma variável membro da classe defina o modificador de acesso e depois seu nome

public - é acessivel por todas os métodos da classe e fora dela também.

protected - acessivel apenas dentro da classe e suas derivadas.

private - acessivel apenas detros dos métodos da classe.

```
class Teste{
   public $variavel = 'esse valor pode ser modificado externamente';

   public function foo(){
     echo $this->variavel;
   }
}
```